# angular dynamic view child in ngFor

Tags: angular, ng-bootstrap

I'm trying to get the component instance using `@ViewChild` which is in `ngFor` of ng-bootstrap tabs, however I'm only getting the first component instance even though I'm changing the tabs along with `component` and its `inputs`.

#### Update

I even tried with `@ViewChildren' but i'm getting inconsistent results.

Please see the [Plunker2](http://plnkr.co/edit/efHibA?p=preview) for the how it is behaving.

Is there anyway I can access the particular component instance in `ngFor` or am I missing something?

#### Version information:

Angular: 2.4.0;
ng-bootstrap: 1.0.0-alpha.20

#### Component:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <ngb-tabset (tabChange)="tabChanged($event)">
      <ngb-tab *ngFor="let item of tabs;let tIdx = index;" [title]="item.slice(0,10)">
        <template ngbTabContent>
          <app-grid [content]="item" #grid></app-grid>
        </template>
      </ngb-tab>
    </ngb-tabset>
  `
})

export class App {
  @ViewChild('grid') grid: GridComponent;
  tabs=[
    `Raw denim you probably haven't heard of them jean shorts Austin.`,
      `Food truck fixie locavore, accusamus mcsweeney's marfa nulla single-origin coffee squid.`,
      `Mustache cliche tempor, williamsburg carles vegan helvetica.`]
  tabChanged(event){
    debugger;
    console.log(this.grid);
    alert(this.grid.content);
  }
}
```

#### Demo

[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/A3YnV1?p=preview)
[Plunker2](http://plnkr.co/edit/efHibA?p=preview)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**EDIT**:

Those components are template-based and only get instantiated once you visit each tab. You can test this with a `console.log` inside the grid component `onInit`.

So they cannot be available from the start (when the main app component is instantiated). Only the first tab is created at this point.

To access the component instances you need to make sure all tabs are activated one way or another first.

You can use an `EventEmitter` to keep track, but then you need to manually emit events from the grid - this can be a flexible approach though. You can emit the content as well as the component instance itself

```
export class GridComponent implements OnInit { 
 @Input() content:string;
 @Output() contentChanged = new EventEmitter<string>();

 ngOnInit(){
  setInterval(() => {
    this.content = this.content + ' xxx ';
    this.contentChanged.emit({ content: this.content, controller: this });
  }, 2000);
}
```

Then assign an event handler

```
<template ngbTabContent>
  <app-grid [content]="item" (contentChanged)="changed(tIdx, $event)"></app-grid>
</template>
```

And you can use this to keep track

```
changed(tIdx, { content, controller }) {
  console.log(tIdx + " : " + content);
  console.log(controller);
}
```

See plnkr.co/edit/c6m3QyDSd0fWpoJUvTh7?p=preview

**Original issue**

You can use `@ViewChildren` instead, which allows you to select multiple components into an array as so:

```
@ViewChildren(GridComponent) grids: QueryList<GridComponent>; // select by component type but you could also use css - using id however is not ok for multiple items

tabChanged(event){
  debugger;
  console.log(this.grids.toArray());
  alert(this.grids.toArray().map(g => g.content));
}
```

And since you're not using the id to select the component anymore you can remove it

```
<template ngbTabContent>
  <app-grid [content]="item"></app-grid>
</template>
```

Comment: Did you try that one? I've tried with ViewChildren also but it is behaving inconsistently means Initially the variable contains one instance and if I change tabs it is keeps on pushing to that variable.

Comment: yes, I'm using it in our project and it works correctly - what exactly happens if you use it in your context?

Comment: ups, just realized we're binding this to a `QueryList<...>` see update

Comment: Give me a second I'm preparing another plunker

Comment: You're still using the ID but indeed I see what you mean, it must be related to how the tab component is implemented. It must create those templates over and over into the view whenever you switch onto the tab.

Comment: It is behaviour is same as its used to be eventhough I've used @ViewChildren without template reference variable

Comment: well I think the problem is those components are not created from the start - they're just a template. Only once you move on the tab each component is created, so even if there were a way to find them, it's only possible to find them once you have visited all the tabs. Can you explain more what you're actually trying to do and why you need them from the start?

Comment: Let me tell first say thank you for your response. I'm trying to track the component content while the tabs with the grid component are changing. In simple It is like multi step form each step contains the same component. I need to check the components contents before proceding to next step

Comment: I've created the plunker for demonstration purpose. The gridComponent contains editable table. and when the tab changes I need to check whether the grid is in editable mode. For that I have to access the grid component variable which is why I wanted to get the grid instance

Comment: I guess you can use an EventEmitter to keep track ,but then you need to manually emit events from the grid - this is more flexible though. You can emit the content as well as the component instance itself - see http://plnkr.co/edit/c6m3QyDSd0fWpoJUvTh7?p=preview